# PowerPoint Animation Behaviours

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to change the default blue color that powerpoint uses through its animations. Specifically, I would like to use animations such as msoAnimEffectCheckerboard with vba.

Is there a reliable and easy to use website that explains how to do this?

Thanks,
Peter.

The following code works but doesn't do anything to the color.

```
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(3)
     Set shp2 = .Shapes("A3")

     .TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect shp2, msoAnimEffectCheckerboard, , msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious
     .TimeLine.MainSequence(1).Timing.Duration = 2
     .TimeLine.MainSequence(1).Timing.TriggerDelayTime = 2
    End With
```

Comment: Default blue color? I have no idea what you're referring to. I ran your code and don't see any blue in the animation.

Comment: I see what you mean. I thought it was the same problem as happens with msoAnimEffectChangeFillColor which has a default color of orange. I would like to change its default color if possible.

Sorry for the run around

Answer (score 0):

**msoAnimEffectChangeFillColor** doesn't have a default color. It uses the colors set in your color theme. It changes the color to **Accent 2** by default. But you can change that in the **Effect Options** dialog on the **Effect** tab. Or your can edit your color theme to change the available colors.